# How to avoid execution timeout error with async requests

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, .net-core, task

I have the below method, Where I am performing the tasks and returning the bool variable to the caller. Even though I am asynchronously running the tasks, using the task scheduler, and running these tasks parallel, I still get the timeout error.

```
private static async Task<bool> CreateSimulationJob( 
        APIDbContext dbContext,
        ITopicEventSender eventSender,
        IEmployeeContext employeeContext,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        SimulationDto input,
        Guid id,
        Project project,
        BuildingStory buildingStory, 
        ICollection<string> insertedIds,
        ICollection<string> errors)
    {
        bool ok = false;
        bool isSimulationCreated = false;
        var simulation = new LoadSimulation() { Id = id, ...};         
        try
        {
            var builder = new OsmBuilder(project, dbContext, employeeContext);
            var director = new OsmDirector(builder);
            var buildOsmTask = director.BuildOsmAsync(buildingStory?.Id);
            var modelTask = buildOsmTask.ContinueWith(task => builder.GetOsm(), TaskScheduler.Default);
            var idfTextTask = modelTask.ContinueWith(task => ProjectUtils.GenerateIDFTextAsync(task.Result), TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
            var responseTask = SendPostRequestAsync(input.ProjectNumber, simulation.Id, idfTextTask, configuration);

            var dbContextTask = dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            var loadSimulationEventTask = SendSimulationUpdatedEvent(eventSender, simulation);
            await Task.WhenAll(buildOsmTask, idfTextTask, responseTask, dbContextTask, loadSimulationEventTask).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var response = await responseTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                simulation.StatusId = LoadSimulationStatus.SCHEDULED.Id;
                simulation.JobId = response.Content;
                simulation.LastUpdatedAtUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
                dbContext.LoadSimulationRuns.Add(simulation);

                await dbContextTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
                await dbContext.Entry(simulation).LoadNavigations().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await loadSimulationEventTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

                ok = true;
                insertedIds.Add($"{simulation.Id}.{simulation.JobId}");
            }
            else
            {
                errors.Add(response.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.Add(ex.ToString());              
        }
        return ok;
    }
    
    private static async Task<RestResponse> SendPostRequestAsync(string projectNumber, Guid simulationId, Task<string> idfTextTask, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var idfText = await idfTextTask.ConfigureAwait(false); // Mostly this is where the process is taking more time to execute
        var client = new RestClient(configuration["Endpoints:SimulationServer"]);
        var request = new RestRequest($"api/simulation/{projectNumber}/{simulationId}", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        request.AddParameter("text/plain", idfText, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response;
    }
```

Could anyone please let me know in any other way to reduce the execution time? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: What exactly ends in the timeout?

Comment: Also for long-running jobs I would recommend to switch from request-response pattern to something like SignalR or polling approach.

Comment: The execution timeout is set to 30 secs by default, and the below line takes more than that`var idfText = await idfTextTask.ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: My guess is that not much can be done here, especially without seeing the taks itself. Also I suggest to dump the `ContinueWith`'s and just move "pipeline" into separate method with simple awaits. You need to measure what takes the most of the time and try to optimize that, but it can be impossible, so you will need to rethink the approach completely.

Comment: You should focus on optimizing the `ProjectUtils.GenerateIDFTextAsync` method. Nothing can be done from outside, if the code inside is slow. If you want help, consider including this method in the question.